# How can I delete a few characters from kendoautocomplete box

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I have location autocomplete textbox. After selecting the location I want to delete some part of that location but not the entire location.

Example:
My location is `154`, I want to make it to `15`. How can I do this?

```
$("#locations").on("keydown", function () {
    var locations = $(this).val();
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if (key == 8 || key == 46)
        $("#locations").data("kendoAutoComplete").value("");
});
```

But with the help of this code I'm able to delete the entire location but I'm not able to delete some part of the location.

Comment: What is the criteria behind deleting the characters in the location?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find a substring, and, if needed, add another substring.

```
location.substring(0,2)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example to show that your approach works? Thereby you can verify your solution. As it stands now it is an assumption that might work.

Comment: location.substring(0,2)

Comment: actually my question is that how can i delete with the help of backspace  by removing individual character example 156 is my location field value,i want to delete 156 with the help of backspace  by deleting individual no

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the select event of the autocomplete and update the datasource to achieve this. 
I have made a JSBin for this issue [here](http://jsbin.com/wusawugebo/edit?html,js,output)

Hope this helps!